# Empty json object instead of null, when no data -> how to deserialize with gson

Tags: java, json, null, deserialization, gson

I am trying to parse json data with Google's gson library. But the json data doesn't behave well.

It does look like this when everything is alright:

```
{
    "parent": {
        "child_one": "some String",
        "child_two": "4711",
        ...
    }
}
```

`child_one` should be parsed as `String`, `child_two` as `int`. 
But sometimes one of the children has no values what results in an empty object instead of `null`, like this:

```
{
    "parent": {
        "child_one": "some String",
        "child_two": {},
        ...
    }
}
```

I have no access to alter the json feed, so I have to deal with it during deserialization.
But I am lost here. If I just let it parse the 2nd case gives me a `JsonSyntaxException`.

**I thought about using a custom `JsonDeserializer`. Do there something like inspect every element if it is a `JsonObject` and if it is, check if the `entrySet.isEmpty()`. If yes, remove that element.**
But I have no idea how to accomplish the iterating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `TypeAdapter<String>`'s `read` method like this:

```
public String read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    boolean nextNull = false;
    while (reader.peek() == JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY || reader.peek() == JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
        reader.skipValue();
        nextNull = true;
    }
    return nextNull ? null : reader.nextString();
}
```

Explain: when next token is `[` or `]`, just skip it and return null.

If you replace all `[]` to `null` use `String#replaceAll` directly, some real  string may be replaced as well, This may cause some other bugs.

Answer (score 5):

Can't you just replace {} with NULL before passing it to the GSON?

Comment: `null` would still be invalid as OP has to parse to `int`.

Comment: @Adassko That was the right idea. I simply had to do this to the data, before passing it: `json.toString().replace("{}", "null");`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `null` is fine, as gson handles the parsing. :)

Comment: Key can also be an object or an array. So it is not useful to run replace().

Comment: How this seriously could be the accepted answer is beyond me. Instead of writing code that successfully parses JSON containing empty objects - which is perfectly valid - you're suggesting manually avoiding it by string substitution before parsing?