# Gson parse {} to null object

Tags: android, gson

I define a model User like this

```
public class User{
    public String name;
    public String avatar;
    public String desc;
}
```

And using gson to parse the empty json string like this

```
{}
```

to User Object.

I get a User object with all fields is null. How can i get a null user object directly?

Comment: Get directly from `gson`?

Comment: `User user = new User()`

Comment: Server api give me empty json string : {} . The gson.fromJson(str) will return a User Object. How can i get a null.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750908/empty-json-object-instead-of-null-when-no-data-how-to-deserialize-with-gson

Answer (score 0):

output can be `{}` if your object's fields are not set. Try below code:

```
User user = new User();

// you probably forgot to set values of user object
user.name = "your name";
user.avatar = "your avatar;
user.desc = "your desc";

Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonStr = gson.toJson(obj);
```

**Output:**

```
{
  name: "your name",
  avatar: "your avatar",
  desc: "your desc"
}
```

Comment: the question is that :Server api give me empty json string : {} . The gson.fromJson(str) will return a User Object. How can i get a null.